# Compiling vim with python has wrong version

Tags: python, vim

Compiled vim with python 2.7.9 using the

```
--with-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir Software/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/config
```

You can see that it seems to be compiled with python2.7.9 from the output

```
$> python --version
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux     -L/Software/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

However, when I run the following within VIM it seems python 2.7.3 is what is detected(There is no python 2.7.3 anywhere on my system)

```
:python import sys; print sys.version
2.7.3 (default, Apr 29 2014, 14:50:10)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]
```

Seems very strange that 2.7.3 would be reported here. I suspect it is causing another issue I am having

```
:python import virtualenv;
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: Software/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt
```

Very strange since it seems that python is setup correctly from the shell

```
$> echo $PYTHONHOME
Software/Python-2.7.9
$> echo $PYTHONPATH
Software/Python-2.7.9/lib
$> python -c "import virtualenv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently because I had an old /usr/local version of python2.7.3 that was not fully uninstalled it was partially using it.

I removed all directories from /usr/local that were part of python2.7.3 and recompiled and now it seems to work